# Cannot inject JpaRepository using annotation @Autowired in spock

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spock

I have the following test class in spock.

```
@DataJpaTest
@SpringBootTest(classes = MainSpring.class)
@ContextConfiguration
class AccountRepositorySpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    def "Example test"(){
        given:
        int k=1
        expect:
        1==1
    }
}
```

This is a repository JPA interface.

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, String> {
}
```

In debug mode each time when I run test, accountRepository is null.
What could be the problem.

This is my pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-groovy-2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <groups>com.microservices.accountservice.UnitTest</groups>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

I configured my project in that way in order to run Junit and Spock Unit Tests. Also I am using postgresql jdbc. The problem is that I cannot inject any components like Services, Respositories or RestControllers in Spock Tests using the following annotations. In Junit Unit Tests I have the same issues. Is anyone has the same problems previously in project?

Comment: `gmavenplus-plugin` configured? (maven/gradle?) ..has the (extra) `@ContextConfiguration` any (hidden) purpose?

Comment: for investigation: try to autowire/debug  `ApplicationContext`...

Comment: @xerx593 I added pom.xml regarding to maven.

Comment: @xerx593 I tried with option
    Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
And the same result is null

Comment: comparing with [baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-spock-testing) ... i am missing the `spock-spring` (test) dependency..

Comment: @xerx593 thanks.
However my maven 3.6 cannot find in groupId org.spockframework artifact spock-spring.

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.spockframework/spock-spring/1.1-groovy-2.4 !?

Comment: @xerx593, everyting works fine, maven had some problems with importing dependencies.

Comment: @xerx593 please provide it as this as an answer so that you can get some rep, and this questions is marked as answered.

Comment: thank you for the rep.! :) but i am not sure what to answer!? xD xD ... I am glad, it helped! :):)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## One possible reason

... for this behavior can be, that your `spock-spring` maven-dependency is:

- completely missing (in your pom).
- corrupted/broken in your local maven repository .

To fix this, please:

- ensure the dependecy is declared in your pom.
- ..and reliably available in your local repo.